# How do I use a block-level element as a background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently working on my first fully responsive website and as it seems I'm kinda stuck. Also I would provide a fiddle but I am still learning how to use it,

Everything works like a charm, but I am still learning which means that I will occur a problem or two. I've tried different codes, trying to change the
`background: url(.cycle-slideshow);`

I am trying to use the

```
    .cycle-slideshow {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

as a background so I can use this ontop of the background, because as you can see its hiding behind the slideshow.

```
/*Menu CSS*/

            #sidebar {
                background: #151718;
                width: 200px;
                height: 17%;
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                left: -200px;
                top: 0px;
                transition: left 0.3s linear;
            }

                #sidebar.visible {
                    left: 0px;
                    transition: left 0.3s linear;
                }

            ul {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

                ul li {
                    list-style: none;
                }

                    ul li a {
                        background: #1C1E1F;
                        color: #ccc;
                        border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
                        display: block;
                        width: 180px;
                        padding: 10px;
                        text-decoration: none;
                    }

            #sidebar-btn {
                display: inline-block;
                vertical-align: middle;
                width: 20px;
                height: 150px;
                cursor: pointer;
                margin: 20px;
                position: absolute;
                top:0px;
                right:-60px;
            }

                #sidebar-btn span {
                    height: 1px;
                    background: #111;
                    margin-bottom: 5px;
                    display: block;
                }

                    #sidebar-btn span:nth-child(2) {
                        width: 75%;
                    }

                    #sidebar-btn span:nth-child(3) {
                        width: 50%;
                    }



/*Menu CSS*/
```

but I cant seem to get it to work with HTMl, will I have to use a JQuery function to get it to work?

Here is the source code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Full Width Responsive Image Slider</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
            html, body, img {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                background: url(.container);
            }

            body {
                font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial;
            }

        .container {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            .cycle-slideshow {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                display: block;
                position: relative;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }

            .cycle-prev, .cycle-next {
                font-size: 200;
                color: #FFF;
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                margin-top: -16px;
                z-index: 9999;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            .cycle-prev {
                left: 10%;
            }

            .cycle-next {
                right: 10%;
            }

            .cycle-pager {
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                position: top;
                bottom: 20px;
                z-index: 9999;
            }

                .cycle-pager span {
                    text-indent: 100%;
                    white-space: nowrap;
                    ;
                    width: 12px;
                    height: 12px;
                    display: inline-block;
                    border: 1px solid #FFF;
                    border-radius: 50%;
                    margin: 0 10px;
                    cursor: pointer;
                }

                .cycle-pager .cycle-pager-active {
                    background: #FFF;
                }


/*Menu CSS*/

            #sidebar {
                background: #151718;
                width: 200px;
                height: 17%;
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                left: -200px;
                top: 0px;
                transition: left 0.3s linear;
            }

                #sidebar.visible {
                    left: 0px;
                    transition: left 0.3s linear;
                }

            ul {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

                ul li {
                    list-style: none;
                }

                    ul li a {
                        background: #1C1E1F;
                        color: #ccc;
                        border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
                        display: block;
                        width: 180px;
                        padding: 10px;
                        text-decoration: none;
                    }

            #sidebar-btn {
                display: inline-block;
                vertical-align: middle;
                width: 20px;
                height: 150px;
                cursor: pointer;
                margin: 20px;
                position: absolute;
                top:0px;
                right:-60px;
            }

                #sidebar-btn span {
                    height: 1px;
                    background: #111;
                    margin-bottom: 5px;
                    display: block;
                }

                    #sidebar-btn span:nth-child(2) {
                        width: 75%;
                    }

                    #sidebar-btn span:nth-child(3) {
                        width: 50%;
                    }



/*Menu CSS*/




    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="sidebar">

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>


    <div id="sidebar-btn">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </div>




    </div>

    <!-- Full Width Responsive Slider -->

    <div class="container">

            <div class="cycle-slideshow">
            <span class="cycle-prev">〈</span>
            <span class="cycle-next">〉</span>
            <span class="cycle-pager"></span>
            <img src="images/picOne.jpg">
            <img src="images/picTwo.jpg">
            <img src="images/picThree.jpg">
          </div>
        <!-- Full Width Responsive Slider -->

        </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#sidebar-btn').click(function(){
            $('#sidebar').toggleClass('visible');

        });
    }); 
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an element to be layered on top of another, much like the layers in a Photoshop document, you can use the z-index property.  z-index requires the element you use it on to have positioning other than static.  Lower numbers for z-index mean lower layers - the higher the number, the more "in front" of other layers the element would be.

So if your #sidebar element is hiding behind / under the slideshow, try this:

```
#sidebar {
    background: #151718;
    width: 200px;
    height: 17%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -200px;
    top: 0px;
    transition: left 0.3s linear;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 900;
}
```

Since the .container element has a z-index that is lower than #sidebar, it will appear behind the sidebar.

By default, without z-index being explicitly set in your CSS, elements will layer according to their occurrence in the DOM, with items that happen farther down the DOM being on top.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: Wow! Thats amazing! I had no idea! Sorry I mainly program in C#! Thanks for providing me the help & link Tammy!

Answer (score 0):

As for the background property, the correct way to write is

```
background: url(IMAGE PATH);
ex. background: url('images/photo.jpg');
```

Also, when you use background image, make it sure to use with

```
background-size: cover or contain or manual px;
background-position: 50% 50%;
```

*Note: Those two properties do not work with old IE browsers.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Thats for changing the background of the website I would like to use my CSS Slideshow that I created as a background, is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible with using css animation, keyframe. Please keep in mind this property does work +IE 10. If you would like to cover the older ones, you need to use javascript.

Comment: To have images as backgrounds, there a many methods. Here's a sample of the latest and efficient way:

`
.cycle-slideshow {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
display: block;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
}`

If i want to use the slideshow but as background, cant I just make some changes based on the sample and make it as background cover? If that is true I still dont know how I would do it.